# How is the Future automatically converted to a Observable?

Tags: python, reactive-programming, future

The code is here:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY/blob/master/examples/autocomplete/autocomplete_asyncio.py#L63

```
searcher = query.flat_map_latest(search_wikipedia)

def search_wikipedia(term):
    """Search Wikipedia for a given term"""
    url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'

    params = {
        "action": 'opensearch',
        "search": term,
        "format": 'json'
    }
    # Must set a user agent for non-browser requests to Wikipedia
    user_agent = "RxPY/1.0 (https://github.com/dbrattli/RxPY; dag@brattli.net) Tornado/4.0.1"

    url = url_concat(url, params)

    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    return http_client.fetch(url, method='GET', user_agent=user_agent)
```

The function search_wikipedia return a Future, while Observable.flat_map_latest() accept a function which should return an observable.

My question is,
How is the Future returned by search_wikipedia() automatically converted to an Observable? 
There is a [Observable.from_future()](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY/blob/master/rx/linq/observable/fromfuture.py) can convert a Future to an Observable. But it should be called explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer,
[Observer.flat_map()](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY/blob/master/rx/linq/observable/selectmany.py) detect parameter type and call from_future() if